# Estimate Number of People

Tags: maximum-likelihood

In stats we just finished learning about the theory behind MLEs, so I presume this question has something to do with them ... but there is so little information I have no idea where to begin.

You work in a library which has one and only one copy of Harry Potter and the 
sorcerers Stone.  You have data from the last 20 Monday's about whether not the 
book was checked out at the time the library closes.

CCCCN CCCCN CCCCN CCCCC

C represents checked out and N not checked out. Give an estimate of the number 
of people who want to check out the book on any given Monday.  I have no idea what we can do to form an estimate of the NUMBER of people interested in the book. I only can see questions relating to the probability it will be checked out. Any suggestions/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) What is a "mel"? (2) The only information you have about numbers of people is that there is at least one person using the library (because the book has been checked out before). From just these data you cannot possibly know whether one person or a billion people would like to check it out on any given day. You need to make assumptions that relate numbers of people to the chance of the book being checked out.

Comment: I suggest it is MLEs based on the tag

Comment: yes, "mel" is supposed to read "mle's". That was my phones autocorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Well... let's take the question at face value. You need to provide an estimate. The question does not say or imply there is a single correct answer. There also isn't a single correct answer assuming you have given us all possible information.

Assumption: if someone wanted the book on a Monday, they would have it, unless it checked out.

Therefore, on weeks that it is checked in, 0 people want the book.

Assumption: if someone wants the book, their desire does not change until they have it.

Therefore, on week 1, no more than 4 people want the book (person 1 gets it that week, then person 2 gets it the next week, etc.). Magically on week 6 people want it again. Exactly 4 people apparently. The last 5 weeks you have to guess at. It could be 1 person each week, or a billion people each week. So let's just make an *estimate.*

$$mean(4,3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1) = 1.75$$

If this is homework and you want to be snarky, turn in this one to your professor though.
$$mean(4,3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,0,1 billion,1 billion,1 billion,1 billion,1 billion) = 250,000,001.5$$

Alternatively, perhaps you are merely supposed to provide a way to estimate it. That would allow you to make up a lot of stuff. You'd basically invent a regression equation with # of people who want a book as the DV, and one of your IVs would be whether or not it is checked out of the library. Other IVs would be variables of interest that you don't have data for, like whether or not the library was closed for repairs. If the book was returned at the end of the day. If it was sunny that day. Whether or not a local fundamentalist was protesting the library's lack of a censorship policy regarding books on magic.

Comment: I agree. An assumption fueled answer is definitely possible with the limited information. +1 to @le_andrew

Comment: "Whether or not a local fundamentalist was protesting the library's lack of a censorship policy regarding books on magic." I read this on my phone at a red light.... and almost crashed my car. That was hysterical ....

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about interest related to the book, so I agree with you there. As for probability of checking out the book on a given Monday, I would naively say there is an 85% the book will be checked out on any given Monday (17/20 = 0.85). We could also naively say that there is a 100% certainty that the book will be checked out the first four weeks of every 5 week cycle (16/16) and that there is a 25% probability that the book will be checked out every fifth week of the cycle (1/4).

Furthermore, I would not put too much weight into having data about the "last 20 Mondays" without knowing anything about external factors (ex. weather conditions, time of year, number of visitors in the library, etc.). We can play sequence games with this type of data all day, as we could guess that the next four 5 week cycles would look as follows:

CCCCN CCCCN CCCCN CCCCC

In other words, too little data to have any confidence in our "predictions".

Comment: This is my logic, but this is the ONLY information given.  I gather we are supposed to estimate the number of people who want to rent the book and write it as a function of $n$ if, say, $n$ is the number of people in the city.

Comment: Oh trust me, I completely understand @GeorgeTedder, my answer was more geared at the frustration that you likely have regarding this problem. So limited data, which as I mentioned in my below comment, forces us to create an assumption fueled solution. Transparency of logic is always key with those types of solutions.